# Get the web User's timezone as string

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a site, and where the users will  be uploading questions and answers in it. Now I need to get the user's timezone which i can store it in variable $TimeZoneNameTo instead of just "Asia/Kathmandu". is there anyway, where the time zone as a string will be detected and stroed in variable  $TimeZoneNAmeTo, so for any user of any timezone, the datetime will be converter to his/her timezone instead of UTC while displaying.

```
$TimeZoneNameFrom="UTC";
    $TimeZoneNameTo="Asia/Kathmandu";
echo "uploaded on".$upload_date;
    echo"<br>";
    echo date_create($upload_date, new DateTimeZone($TimeZoneNameFrom))
    ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($TimeZoneNameTo))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is present times based on the user's system settings, then just send UTC time values to the client. The value should be milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. UNIX uses seconds since the same epoch, so you just need a UNIX UTC timestamp multiplied by 1000:

```
var newLocalDate = new Date(UNIXutcTimeValue * 1000);
```

Now just present it in a user readable form, say using [*Date.prototype.toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.5):

```
alert(newLocalDate.toLocaleString());
```

e.g. 2014-06-06T12:00:00Z is 1402056000 seconds or 1402056000000 milliseconds, so in Safari:

```
alert(new Date(1402056000000).toLocaleString()) // 6 June 2014 20:00:00 AWST
```

Of course you can always use Date methods to format the string anyway you want.

Comment: +1 because yes, for OP's problem, knowing the user timezone seems to be useless, he doesn't have to take the hard path...

Comment: tq for your annswer.. :)

Comment: @mehhancy if the answer is good for you, you should consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

**Answering the question you ask :**

On modern browsers you can fetch the timezone client side using

```
var tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolved.timeZone;
```

If your browser doesn't have [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) (IE10- and Safari), then it's a little more complicated. I made a small library for that using moment.js : https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js

**Answering the problem you have :**

Most of the times you *don't have* to know the client's timezone and you can simply let his browser format a UTC timestamp you send. See RobG's answer.

Comment: Intl is not supported in Safari.

Comment: @RobG Damn... What are they doing ?

Comment: Though might not be supported in safari... bt your answer helped @dystroy :)

Comment: @dystroy—dunno, would be much better as a methods of Date though. Note there is no standard for timezones, just databases for what is in use (and they change reasonably regularly).

Comment: @RobG The Olson tables are so widely used. I see the IANA data as a standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database